# How can I integrate jQuery UI's drag and drop with files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I want to be able to drag and drop files into different places in the page to mean different things. I am already using jQuery UI's drag and drop interface and it would be nice if I could integrate that somehow with the file interface. Does anyone know of a plugin that does this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing library, but it's not too difficult to make something from scratch: http://jsfiddle.net/P3KJA/2/. If there is a state-of-the-art library available you of course should use it, but this fiddle might be a start if there are none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you given a look to "elfinder"? Not only provides drag and drop but all sorts of features (permissions, filters, upload, remove, rename).

http://elfinder.org/

Hope it helps.
-JJ

Comment: I think on file upload with drag and drop is required.